# Failed to call Asp.net method from Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to call Asp.Net function from Javascript. I have a sample which is calling Asp.net MVC funciton like that.

```
@{
    var payUrl = "/recordings/recording-123.wav";

    <!-- saves the wav file to local folder called recodings using a session value to make unique file names -->
}
    function setupRecorder() {
        Wami.setup({
            id: "wami",
            onReady: setupGUI
        });
    }

    function setupGUI() {
        var gui = new Wami.GUI({
            id: "wami",
            recordUrl: "http://localhost:5296/home/Save",
            playUrl: "@payUrl"
        });

        gui.setPlayEnabled(false);
    }
```

Here is the exact calling from the code

```
recordUrl: "http://localhost:5296/home/Save",
```

The HomeController has a method Save which is being called here

```
public ActionResult Save()
        {
            Request.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/recordings/recording-123.wav"), false);
            return Json(new { Success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I want the exact thing in Asp.Net but i am not able to find the solution if anyone out there can help me out i would be thankful to you this is the only part left in my project i simply need to save the audio. I am doing like this

```
<script>
    function setupRecorder() {
        Wami.setup({
            id: "wami",
            onReady: setupGUI
        });
    }

    function setupGUI() {
        var gui = new Wami.GUI({
            id: "wami",
            recordUrl: "Default.aspx/Save",
            playUrl: "/recordings/recording-123.wav"
        });

        gui.setPlayEnabled(false);
    }
</script>
```

I have a webform Default.aspx which has method save

```
recordUrl: "Default.aspx/Save",
```

This is the exact default.aspx.cs method. I have tried  [HttpGet] and [httpPost] both nothing is working for me .

```
 [HttpGet]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public void Save()
        {
            Request.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/recordings/recording-123.wav"), false);
            return Json(new { Success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: try using fully qualified url rather than short one

Comment: what do you mean by full url? if i use this recordUrl: "Default.aspx", then it is going on the Page_load method but i want it to find the save method@qamar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your save method needs to be marked as static since its a webmethod. Only then you should to be able to call it from JS

```
  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
  public static void Save()
    {
        Request.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/recordings/recording-123.wav"), false);
        return Json(new { Success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```